# Methods (PUT, UPDATE, DELETE) that are not supported in some routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm having some problems about some routes that don't support certain methods.

```
// The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
Route::post('/action_create_hunter', [HunterController::class, 'store'])->name('action_create_hunter.store');

<form action="{{ url("action_create_hunter") }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    .....
```

```
// The UPDATE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
Route::post('/action_update_hunter/{id}', [HunterController::class, 'update'])->name('action_update_hunter.update');

<form action="{{ url("action_update_hunter/$hunter->id") }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    .....
```

```
// The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.
Route::delete('/delete_hunter/{id}', [UserController::class, 'destroy'])->name('action_delete_hunter.destroy');

<a href="{{ url("delete_hunter/$hxh->id") }}" class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete {{ $hxh->name_hunter }}"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>
```

Comment: The errors are pretty clear, you’ve not defined routes to support those particular HTTP verbs. Read the Laravel documentation on [basic routing](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#basic-routing).

Answer (score 1):

You should define a hidden input with the Method name in this case , and for Laravel you can use @method , for example , If you want this be Put Method

The Route Will be

```
Route::put('/action_update_hunter/{id}', [HunterController::class, 'update'])->name('action_update_hunter.update');
```

And The form :

```
<form action="{{ url("action_update_hunter/$hunter->id") }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @method('put')

....
</form>
```

it's called Form Method Spoofing , check it in laravel docs For more information

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#form-method-spoofing